# How would I make the true results of this awk command issue a command like sendmail etc

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, arguments

I'm trying to create a script that checks the 5th value of every line in a CSV output. For instance:

```
AAA,111,222,333,1
```

Here is what I am using:

```
awk -F "," '{if ($5 > 10) print $1 " has a value of " $5}' results
```

I was missing the "," ... what I was hoping to create is that if the results were in fact greater, True, then I could issue a command like sendmail with the results. if false do nothing.

Comment: "it hasn't yielded results" What hasn't yielded results? You didn't share your code.

Comment: Show your code. Give the exact input, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do what you say you want is:

```
awk -F, '{printf "1st-column-value has 5th-column-value %s than 10\n", ($5>10 ? "greater" : "less")}' file
```

but of course your logic is wrong (consider `equal to 10`) and idk if you actually wanted the first column value printed instead of just the text `1st-column-value` as you state in your question, and so on since you didn't include concise, testable sample input and expected output in your question.